# Hide StatusBar in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2, cordova-2.0.0

I have build a app using Ionic 2.When i run it in browser,the UI is looking good but as soon as i run in iOS simulator,everything seems bulky.The issue is with Status bar.I need to hide the status bar.I tried with StatusBar from ionic-native,like this-

```
    import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.hide();
      //StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
```

But in reality its not hiding the status bar,instead its just overriding status bar colour with my page header colour.Any solution of hiding status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on ionic3 and hope it will work for ionic 2 also.
I was also in the need of same and here is my local setup-

```
li packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

Now make changes in following files as-

*config.xml*

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

*Component.ts*

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
```

That worked for me.

> Note:- Changes will reflect in simulator or android phone only, not in
>   browser.

Comment: for me ```<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />``` alone working fine